# Odoo on Google compute engine - refused to connect

Tags: google-compute-engine, odoo, firewall

I am fairly new to both google compute engine and Odoo. I have recently started a google compute engine with Ubuntu-16 installed. I have successfully followed instructions on Odoo website to install and start Odoo server. When I try to access my Odoo instance from another computer by going to 
`IP-address-of-server:8069`

I find

`ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Following are the firewall rules for the instance. Please guide me on how to solve this problem. Please feel free to ask for any additional information.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple things to make sure what exactly is your problem. Check whether odoo service is working by entering `systemctl status odoo-server` 
This should show whether your service is started (and enabled) or not. Check this then reply back.

Also, while accessing your odoo server, use http request instead of https.

Comment: Yes, the service is up and active.

Comment: Check the error logs then. If you're using postgress as your database, the command is `journalctl -u postgresql` . Also, disable the firewalld by `ufw disable` and allow 8089 port by `ufw allow 8069/tcp` command

Comment: Not much in t6he logs, it says -- Logs begin at Tue 2018-06-26 12:45:31 UTC, end at Wed 2018-06-27 06:35:01 UTC. --
Jun 26 12:45:41 odoo systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Jun 26 12:45:41 odoo systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.

Comment: Use the above two commands which I've mentioned in the comment.

Comment: Updated firewall rules, no change. Additionally I tried `curl 127.0.0.1:8069` which gives connection refused as well.

Comment: Type `netstat --listen | grep 8069`
Your port should be listening. If not, then do tell.

Comment: There's your problem!
You haven't configured the 8069 port to listen.
Change the odoo configration file and allow tcp traffic on 8069 by `ufw allow 8069/tcp`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173864/discussion-between-prakhar-singh-and-kanishk-kumar-gupta).

Answer (score 0):

Try if you can connect from the VM itself to Odoo. Log in to your VM with `ssh` and then use `curl localhost:8069` or `wget localhost:8069`. If that's successful, it's a firewall issue.

If it is a firewall problem, add a rule similar to the `default-allow-http`, but for the port you need. Then add the tag of your rule to your VM instance. You can do this in [Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances).